# Algorithm to transform from an expression to a graph (DAG) representation

Tags: algorithm, abstract-syntax-tree, directed-acyclic-graphs, unification

I was reading about unification algorithms and the efficient ones seem to have as input a DAG, where my understanding was that terms that are shared in an expression are not duplicated nodes (as in an AST).

I'm sure there are well known algorithms that convert an expression from a "string representation" or AST to a DAG. 
Do such algorithms exist? I just want to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: *Could someone give some references?* is the kind of question which Stack Overflow actively discourages.  This is explained in the help centre material.

Comment: I know... I'm not really sure how to formulate... I'm looking for a paper or something

Comment: Yes, see [DCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) (Definite clause grammar).

Comment: I am working toward writing a Wiki on DCGs, [this](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/wiki-discussion-how-to-dcg-and-phrase-3/735) might be of use to you in the mean time.

Comment: Don't plan on me making that an answer as it is a link only answer and copying the source just to put in an answer here is not what I consider kosher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily accomplished with memoization while constructing an AST.

As the AST gets built in postorder, when creating each node, check the memoization cache to see if an equivalent node is already present.  If so, use the preexisting node.  Otherwise use the new node and add it to the cache.

When checking the cache for a preexisting node, the children of that node will already have been memoized, so you can compare them by identity rather than reexamining their subgraphs.

Comment: Thank you. I had an intuition about this, but I was afraid maybe it's a naive approach. I'm glad it's not